# Microsoft Graph and PHP - get data

Tags: php, jquery, microsoft-graph-api

I simply want to download the data from the Microsoft graph API.

However, all it tells me at Microsoft's graph documentation is to go the the url (i.e. `get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`).  However, this requires an authorization token.  I have tried doing it using ajax, but it doesn't seem to work.  I find the documentation awful and total lacking in information.

```
var url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users';
var token = '';
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
})
.done(function( data ) {
    if (data.ok) {
        if (data.count > 0) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    } else {
        alert(data.error);
    }
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log('fail');
});
```

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: 1) what do you need to do with their API ? what kind of data do you want to retrieve ? 2) `However, this requires an authorization token` does that mean you don't have one ? 3) if you do have one, don't you have to pass it through the url ? have you checked [Graph scenarios](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/featured_scenarios) and [Graph permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) ? *completely agree on 'documentation awful and total lacking in information'* ^^

Comment: I just want to retrieve basic info like name, username, phone, department.

Comment: when you run this in your browser `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` you see the response -> `error -> code: "InvalidAuthenticationToken" / message: "Bearer access token is empty."` says it all... you need a granted access: if you removed the credentials in this line, you should have mentionned it though `var token = '';` (see also [graph doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users&version=v1.0) if not already done)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph uses Oauth 2.0, which is a complex authentication completed by the target user of your application, where you send them to Microsoft with a series of parameters including your own (not the target user's) application key, and they sign in and then Microsoft sends them back with the "access_token" value you need to put in the Authorization: Bearer header for all subsequent requests.

They have a run down on this process, including registering for the application key, here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user

They also have example code here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start (there is a node.js version, but I am not sure if you can accomplish this authorization piece in simple frontend javascript)

And this is the single most useful way to figure out how API Requests in Graph actually work (but it won't help you with the Oauth stuff): https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer